# rails -vすると Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sourcesとエラーが発生

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsのアプリを作っています。
railsのバージョンを確認しようとすると、下記のようなエラーが発生します。

```
:/var/www/myapp/development/current$ rails -v
Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Gemfileは下記のようになっています。bundle installしても結果は変わりません。
どうしてrailsのバージョンを返してくれないのでしょうか。

お分かりになられる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていだけますと大変幸いです。

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails',  '5.0.3'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6' 
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'payjp'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.6'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.3'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-passenger'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
gem 'capistrano-safe-deploy-to'
gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
```

**The specs are:**

```
ubuntu 16.04
Bundler 1.14.6
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
Rails 5.0.3
capistrano 3
cloud9 (local environment)
nginx 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
unicorn 4.9.0-2build2
```

Comment: おそらく同じエラーだと思います。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757144/your-bundle-is-locked-to-rake-12-0-0-but-that-version-could-not-be-found-in-a

Comment: ありがとうございます、解決しました！

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi よろしければ回答として投稿していただけませんか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 回答を記載しました。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

[ruby on rails - Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757144/your-bundle-is-locked-to-rake-12-0-0-but-that-version-could-not-be-found-in-a)
が同様のエラーです。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41757322/1979953
の回答のとおり

Step1:

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

Step2:

`vendor/bundle` ディレクトリの削除

`bundle install` をリビルドのために行う

Step3:

`gem update bundler` を試す

関連イシュー: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5068